# Show only parts of an image without making it a background-image?

Tags: html, css, dom

I have an image as such:

```
<div id="container">
  <img src="image.jpg">
<div>
```

I want the image to cover the width and height of the container div - right now the image is large and overflows the height of the container. However, I cannot convert it to be a background image.

I have tried:

```
#container {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

but the image still exceeds the height.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve the same effect of filling the div with the image, as you would by using `background-image` and `overflow:none`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know exactly what you need.If you strecth to fit it will become distorted
like this:

width , height equal that of the container.

or else you will have to add css to the image

```
img{
    height: 100%;
    or width: 100% whichever is less 
}
```

thats all you need to do 
 fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/tbfwq/

Cheers !

Comment: if you are not sure, then use `max-height` and `max-width` :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#container img{
width:100%;
}
```

This will set the width of the image equal to the width of its parent div...
Hopefully it will work for you..
Thanks